# Xubuntu broken/slow mouse scroll

Tags: xubuntu, mouse, scrolling, xev

Since I installed Xubuntu onto my laptop, my mouse has been unable to scroll correctly. On xev, it takes around 5 scrolls of the wheel to register one input, while on mousepad and other applications, it works normally except for it being extremely slow. I can't find any solutions in the settings or online. Hoping I can find a solution here. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve it. It was caused by a file I made trying to make natural mouse scrolling for every application. I tried to find the tutorial that I followed to post it here but failed to find it. I will update this if I come across it.